# What does LV means in MS Access MsysObjects

Tags: microsoft-access

I have linked several MS Access Tables, one has a LV value of "Long Binary Data" in MsysObjects Table whereas the table is only text and all other tables have no such Long Binary Data either.

Comment: Why do you care? I just looked at the table for one of my front ends, and it has lots of items with OLE data in the LV field. Some of the objects are compiled temporary SQL strings, others are linked tables, etc. I would expect that for linked tables, the metadata about the data source on the other side of the link is stored there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is short for ListView, one of the controls in MS Access. ListView means you're viewing the data like this in a list format:

[image]

Long binary data is the type of data you're currently storing into the cells. If you're interested, here is a more in-depth [explanation of long binary data](http://www.ammara.com/support/technologies/long-binary-data.html).

Comment: I don't believe this is correct at all. None of the items in the MSysObjects table that I just examined was a "listview" object (I don't even know what that is in Access terms). Please explain your justification for this answer.

Comment: I said it's a control, not an object. You won't see it in the MSysObjects table.

Comment: I don't have any binary info in this table, but thanks for the article link it's interesting.